# Python - run another python script with current environment passing the arguments over and getting the printed print output

Tags: python, command-line, anaconda

A little bit of an ugly question, but I didn't find existing SO posts which cover it.

Right now I need to use an existing python tool available on this [github](https://github.com/voussoir/timesearch)

This is a rather big piece of code with a lot of dependencies which I don't want to mess with. In a nutshell one can run its module by passing the command line arguments, for example:

```
timesearch.py timesearch -r "subreddit1" -l "1466812800" -up "1498348800"
```

Now, I need to run this tool a bunch of times using a `for` loop, passing over different argument values each time. The tool also prints out some output into command line when you run it - and I would like to intercept and print it out from my python script as well. Finally, I need to ensure that before I move on in my loop and run the tool another time that current execution of the `timesearch` tool is completed.

One side note here - I do need to ensure that the timesearch is executed using same environment which I use to run my main script with for loop.

I am trying to understand what is the best way to do it.

If I just go for this it doesn't work:

```
import os
#for loop will go here
os.system('python timesearch.py timesearch -r "ethereum" -l "1466812800" -up "1498348800"')
```

It fails due to several reasons - it doesn't use the environment in which I am writing my script with a loop, it also doesn't capture the print output of timesearch.

Any advice on how to achieve it?

Just to highlight - I can't just go and pull function I need in timesearch, since it calls the `__init__` to set up some things based on the arguments you pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't call python script with os.system. There is basically one function which you need to use: `main(sys.argv[1:])`

[`https://github.com/voussoir/timesearch/blob/master/timesearch/__init__.py#L435`](https://github.com/voussoir/timesearch/blob/master/timesearch/__init__.py#L435).

Comment: Can we be sure that the __init__ part won't be messed up? I mean will __init__ be called each time I call timesearch.main?

Comment: What do you mean by init part? Is it the part outside the function body? I believe you don't need to create new `ArgumentParser` every time you call main function.